# What is the most effecient way to generate a new random object in java?

Tags: java, oop, object, random, casting

I'm trying to create a randomizer method which will randomly select a new Monster object to be added to my java game. The problem is there are so many different Monster objects, I want to avoid creating multiple unique if() statements in the method.

I currently have an abstract Monster super class with 10 monster subclasses.

My first thought was to create an array of Strings and then convert them to objects, which didn't work:

```
monsterInPlay=monsterRandomizer();

public Monster monsterRandomizer(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    String [] elements = {"bird","zombie","shark",etc...)
    String newMonster = elements[rand.nextInt(9)];
    return new ((Monster)newMonster());
}
```

I imagine making this idea work would require a separate method. So I currently just have 10 separate if() statements which I hate the look of:

```
public Monster monsterRandomizer(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(9);

    if (i==0){
        return new Shark();
    }
    if (i==1){
        return new Zomibie();
    }
    if (i==2){
        return new Bird();
    }

    // and so on....
```

I'm relatively new to java so any help is appreciated. I want to avoid putting 10 different if() statements in my code if at all possible.

Comment: I (and I'm confident most others) have no idea what you want. Is it perhaps that you want to pass one of the `elements` to a constructor of some class? Maybe you should just show your "10 if statements" code

Comment: What kind of object do you want to convert to? Show your code with the if statements and we might be able to help...

Comment: I think you want to create objet with the ramdom() ? Like put all your objects possible into a list, and you creat objet with the element of the list ? If you want to something like this, all your elements should have the same parent class and you use  ParentClass myobjet = new elementOfListe

Comment: return ((Obj)newObj()); => return new Obj(newObj);

Comment: Sorry for being so vague! I edited my post with more context.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are correct, the first one is faster but the problem is that you're returning a "new" variable with double brackets and caste it to a Monster Object which is totally absurd. The keyword `new` is always used before a class name not an instance like `new Monster()` , this will give you a "new" instance of the type Monster.

Instead return a new Monster Object and pass the string to the constructor and then handle the String in the constructor to customize your Monster.

**The method in your code**

```
public Monster monsterRandomizer(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    String [] elements = {"bird","zombie","shark",etc...)
    String newMonster = elements[rand.nextInt(9)];
    return new Monster(newMonster);
}
```

**The constuctor in Monster.java**

```
public Monster(String preset){
    if (preset.equals("bird"){
        //height = ..
        //damage = ..
    } else if (preset.equals("zombie"){
        // ...
    } // else if ...
}
```

If you want to use the second one use `else if` cause it's gonna make the job for computer easier, once the condition is verified it won't have to check every other `if`. It won't make a difference here but it's a good practice for later.

Answer (score 0):

Your example with ifs if called Factory method pattern so it is absolutely valid.

You can also use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(Monster.values().length);
    System.out.println(Monster.values()[i]);
}

enum Monster {
    SHARK,
    ZOMBIE,
    BIRD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
List<Supplier<Monster>> constructors = Arrays.asList(Shark::new, Zombie::new, Bird::new);
int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(constructors.size());
return constructors.get(randomIndex).get();
```